# Company scheduled an interview without asking for availability - red flag?

Tags: interviewing, communication

After 3-4 weeks of silence (I assumed I'd been rejected), got a call from a company that they had scheduled an interview for me - without checking my availability.  It's not the worst time, but I'm feeling scheduling a multi-hour interview without asking me first is a red flag.  Am I over-reacting, or is this something I should be concerned about?

Comment: I'd be far more concerned about the 3-4 weeks personally.

Comment: Sometimes fitting interviews in 1 particular agenda can be tricky. If there are more than 1 people interviewing it could be even trickier. As Joe Strazzere pointed out, it all depends how bad you want the job and how bad they need to fill the position urgently, the one needing it the most should probably be the one being the most flexible

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's very simple (and let's keep it that way):

- If you're okay with that timeslot, send an acknowledgement.
- If you're not okay, request for an alternate time.

Wondering "why" they scheduled without confirming with you first - well, there can be multiple reasons, starting from as simple as a sloppy recruiter (one individual) from a poor company culture. However, I'd suggest not to judge a book by its cover and take another chance. Figure out about the company and work culture as much as possible during the interview process and then you can take the call whether to go ahead or not.

I understand that the long silence observed on the process is already a bad thing usually, but given the current COVID situation, it might be a one-off thing for current time. Given that now onwards things go smooth and as expected, I'd be inclined to ignore that part.

Comment: You might have an incompetent HR person, but get hired into a highly competent team, stay there happily for the next ten years and have no meaningful contact with HR the whole time.

Comment: @gnasher729 That's exactly what I said, HR is not part of your day to day work..so unless absolutely necessary, don't  judge that as the primary factor for a job selection.

Comment: Good on you for not falling into the trap of one bad recruiter = devastatingly bad company culture.

Answer (score 9):

**It skips the tedious back and forth**

*Normal email workflow:*

- Email from company to request interview.
- Email from you to accept and provide interview time.
- Email from them to reject interview time (as they have few spots for it) and ask for another time.
- Email for you to accept time.

*This workflow:*

- Email from company to request interview with suggested time.
- Email from you accepting time.

You can always change the time if you need to, but I would bet the majority of job seekers do not need to change things.

Comment: In my experience, the normal flow is 1)company email, interview intimation and probable slots. 2)  individual to accept a time suited best for them 3) interview. Again, my experience, certainly not standard, but a normal thing here.

Comment: @SouravGhosh generally that has been my experience as well but sometimes I was in the situation mentioned by OP

Comment: @SouravGhosh This is indeed a common practice but this answer is to the point: Any time this technique is used efficiently it's time saved on back and forth (and waiting for responses), and when it doesn't work it's no more effort than if you didn't try...

Answer (score 3):

I've been through couple interview such as

Dual interview: the company scheduling a multi-hour (not asking for availability like your case, in office-hour) and having me and other applicant (probably picked by companies base on CV/resume) presenting profile pro/con. the interview end earlier than the booked time) - booked 3 hrs, finished in about 2 hours

Single interview: the company provide time-slot to picked from. having senior/ director of job position to interview you- hour and a half

First come first serve: more like open-house (office hours), multiple applicant queue to take a test on provided pc, once finished you'll proceed to queue for short interview then free to go home and wait for result

So from my experience it is not that rare for companies to schedule an interview without asking you first
maybe due to their interview process which involved their employee available time, or there is multiple step of interview that required you to take certain test before interview (mine is IT-developer so sometime i have to take short code testing, IQ test or so before interview)

if you still worried about it, you should contract them for further details, asking how the interview process will be like, is the time slot fixed, what do you need to prepare etc. There nothing wrong about asking for clarification.

Answer (score -2):

Not a lot to go on but I'll answer this as best I can.

I've been in interviews in the past where the scheduling of the interview was similar i.e. be here are this time no discussion end of. Of those interviews that I've been to I've never had an offer and most were slow to respond or ghosted me.

I think this probably shows that the hiring manager is extremely busy. So busy in fact that they don't want a discussion with you on when to have the interview as they don't want to rearrange their other appointments.

That could be because of other interviews but it could also be because of work related meetings. I found that these companies were hiring because the current employees were very overworked so they were looking to get someone in to help reduce the amount of work individual employees had to do.

So your question is "Is this a red flag?" my answer is that it's not a red flag for how the company is run / being an employee. It is a red flag for the hiring manager and the interview process itself. I also say that, given my highly limited sample size, if a company is too busy to properly arrange an interview with you they'll be too busy to hire you. Also if the company is in the situation in the first place they are probably very disorganised in general. Waiting a month to get back to someone is also a tell-tale sign.

My advice is to keep looking and if something else comes up then go for that. So don't put much faith in getting anything worthwhile out of this.